# Writing To Text File, File In Use By Another Process, Multithreaded Application .NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Afternoon,

I have a program whereby I really need to be keeping a log of some kind to ascertain what the program is doing. Essentially the software monitors for a window on the desktop to live pause a call recording on our Call Recorder Server.

Lets on argument say a Call Recording itself was pulled up by a monitoring agent and they state that a certain sensitive part of the conversation has been recorded when really it should have been silenced, if they were to say the agent hadn't done their job and clicked the pause recording button OR the onfocus action hadn't occurred I would have a situation whereby I would need to prove what the software was doing at the same.

I decided that I would write the actions of the software to a .txt file stored in the users app data.

This works for the most part, however every now and then even though the .txt is never accessed by any other program I get 'This file is in use by another process'.

This application is multithreaded and does make very frequent calls to write to the log, I am using the below code:

```
Private Sub WriteToLog(ByVal strSubTitle As String, ByVal strLogInfo As String)

    Try
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(strLogFilePath) = True Then

            'Delete yesterdays log file
            Dim strFileDate As Date = File.GetCreationTime(strLogFilePath)
            strFileDate = FormatDateTime(strFileDate, DateFormat.ShortDate)

            'If strFileDate < Date.Today Then
            '    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(strLogFilePath)
            'End If

            Using outFile As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(strLogFilePath, True)

                outFile.WriteLine("" & Date.Today & "," & Date.Now.ToLongTimeString & ", " & strUsername & ", " & strSubTitle & ", " & Replace(strLogInfo, ",", "|") & "")
                outFile.Close()

            End Using
            ''CSV File
            'outFile.WriteLine("" & Date.Today & "," & Date.Now.ToLongTimeString & ", " & strUsername & ", " & strSubTitle & ", " & Replace(strLogInfo, ",", "|") & "")
            'outFile.Close()

        Else

            Using outFile As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(strLogFilePath, False)

                outFile.WriteLine("" & Date.Today & "," & Date.Now.ToLongTimeString & ", " & strUsername & ", " & strSubTitle & ", " & Replace(strLogInfo, ",", "|") & "")
                outFile.Close()

            End Using
            'CSV File
            'outFile.WriteLine("Date, Time, Username, Sub(Process), Information")
            'outFile.WriteLine("" & Date.Today & "," & Date.Now.ToLongTimeString & ", " & strUsername & ", " & strSubTitle & ", " & Replace(strLogInfo, ",", "|") & "")
            'outFile.Close()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        CreateErrorFile(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "Log Write Failure!")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Is there any advice/pointers someone could state as to why this would be saying another process is using the file.

I'm guessing the situation would occur when two separate threads try to do the 'WriteToLog' Sub while one or the other is writing to the file.

Am I on the right tracks? If so how could I rectify this?

Cheers,

James

Comment: Have you considered log4net?  It is free (open source), supports multithreaded applications and the logging is very customizable.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846422/using-log4net-for-multithreaded-application

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi

Answer (score 0):

You will either want to make it so that only one thread has the ability to write to the log file by using the `Invoke` method from the secondary thread(s) to call the write functionality on the main thread, or you can use one of .NET's various synchronization mechanisms.

Here is a simple example of the first approach:

```
Private Sub BackgroundMethod()
    'do stuff
    Me.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf WriteToLog), "write a line blah blah")
    'do more stuff
End Sub

Private Sub WriteToLog(valueToWrite As String)
    System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(MyLogFilePath, {valueToWrite})
End Sub
```

Here's an example using a `SyncLock` block:

```
Private lock As New Object()

Private Sub BackgroundMethod()
    'do stuff
    WriteToLog("write a line blah blah")
    'do more stuff
End Sub

Private Sub WriteToLog(valueToWrite As String)
    SyncLock (lock)
        System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(MyLogFilePath, {valueToWrite})
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

MSDN has good information on synchronization mechanisms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would use a global Queue where new entries get added to and if the log writer is not busy then start it to write down all available lines.

sth like:

```
  Private LogList As New Queue(Of String)
  Private WriterBusy As Boolean = False

  Private Sub WriteToLog(ByVal strSubTitle As String, ByVal strLogInfo As String)

    LogList.Enqueue("" & Date.Today & "," & Date.Now.ToLongTimeString & ", " & strUsername & ", " & strSubTitle & ", " & Replace(strLogInfo, ",", "|") & "")

    If WriterBusy = True Then Exit Sub
    WriterBusy = True

    Try
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(strLogFilePath) = True Then
        ...

        Using outFile As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(strLogFilePath, True)

          While LogList.Count > 0 
              outFile.WriteLine(LogList.Dequeue)
          End While
          outFile.Close()

        End Using
        ...
    End Try

    WriterBusy = False

  End Sub
```